# Trimming a TimeSeries by timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timedelta

I'm trying to remove all "old" values from a pandas TimeSeries, e.g. all values which are more than 1 day old (relative to the newest value).

Naively, I tried something like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
def trim(series):
    return series[series.index.max() - series.index < timedelta(days=1)]
```

Gives an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'
```

Clearly, the problem is with this expression: `series.index.max() - series.index`

I then found this works:

```
def trim(series):
    return series[series.index > series.index.max() - timedelta(days=1)]
```

Can somebody please explain why the latter works while the former raises an error?

EDIT: I am using pandas version 0.12.0

Comment: pls show the series; this needs 0.12 (and maybe 0.13) for proper time delta support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example in 0.13 (`to_timedelta` is not avaiable in 0.12, so
you would have to do `np.timedelta64(4,'D')`)

```
In [12]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='D')

In [13]: ts = pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

In [14]: ts
Out[14]: 
2011-01-01   -0.348362
2011-01-02    1.782487
2011-01-03    1.146537
2011-01-04   -0.176308
2011-01-05   -0.185240
2011-01-06    1.767135
2011-01-07    0.615911
2011-01-08    2.459799
2011-01-09    0.718081
2011-01-10   -0.520741
Freq: D, dtype: float64

In [15]: x = ts.index.to_series().max()-ts.index.to_series()

In [16]: x
Out[16]: 
2011-01-01   9 days
2011-01-02   8 days
2011-01-03   7 days
2011-01-04   6 days
2011-01-05   5 days
2011-01-06   4 days
2011-01-07   3 days
2011-01-08   2 days
2011-01-09   1 days
2011-01-10   0 days
Freq: D, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [17]: x[x>pd.to_timedelta('4 days')]
Out[17]: 
2011-01-01   9 days
2011-01-02   8 days
2011-01-03   7 days
2011-01-04   6 days
2011-01-05   5 days
Freq: D, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks. so I understand using `to_series()` is the key here. Can you please explain why it is needed?

Comment: indexes are not series so they don't have all of the same methods (in this case this will work with ought converting to a series but it's good practice)

Comment: Initially, I didn't expect indexes to be series. I expected them to be `np.array`-like. And I checked that they are indeed derived from `np.ndarray`. That's why I was surprised.

Comment: They are like np.array, but that is going to change, and shouldn't be relied upon

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Truncating and Fancy Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#truncating-fancy-indexing) as follows:

```
ts.truncate(before='Some Date')
```

Example:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

ts.truncate(before=(ts.index.max() - dt.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
```

This should truncate everything before the old date. You can also add a `after` argument to whittle it down further if you desire.